# Capturing data from OBD-II device?

Tags: java, database

So I happen to have a little bit of web experience, and have recently bought an OBD-II device. Basically, I'm trying to log certain metrics from the car, such as location and other diagnostics.

I can send in an SMS to the SIM on the device to configure the server IP that the device sends data to... But I'm not sure what happens next.

A piece of java code that interprets info from the device and makes it available to the PHP & JavaScript applications?

I'm using this: [eeLink](http://en.eelink.com.cn/products/GPS_TRACKER/GOT10.html) OBD - GPS Device...

Comment: What OBD-II device do you have? see http://arduinodev.com/data2kml-utility/ as an example of using Google Earth to display this information geographically.

Comment: Ah, I've added the link to the OBD Device in the original post

Comment: Using the Android SDK you can extract the APP http://www.eelink.com.cn/uploads/datasheet/keelin_traker.apk and use the code to extract the information you are after

Comment: Not a bad idea... will try!